# Send post data from HTML form to RESTful service using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, restful-url

i've just learn about Restful service using codeigniter and created a form, when i submit, i want to send the data to restful service. This is the part of code :

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('/mycontroller/myresource', 'class="form-horizontal"', 'role="form"'); ?>
```

is right if my action target URL resource like code above? if not, can u tell me how to send post data without target my url resource? i'm confused...